# Singleton doesn't return my Object correctly

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to use a singleton to get a `DialogFragment` and this gets the `Dialog` but when try to get this objects and your attributes don't get this.

I want to get the View of my `Dialog`, but this doesn't access the Ids of the layout, here is my `DialogFragment`:

```
 public static class newTaskFragment extends DialogFragment {




        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            // Get the layout inflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();





            // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
            // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_task_dialog, null))
                    // Add action buttons
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.create_task, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            newTaskFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                        }
                    });



            return builder.create();
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            DialogSingleton.getInstance().setDialog(this.getDialog());
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

and here is my singleton:

**DialogSingleton.java**

```
public class DialogSingleton {

        private static DialogSingleton Instance;

        private Dialog mDialog;

        private DialogSingleton(){
            mDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.ma.getApplicationContext());
        }

        public static DialogSingleton getInstance(){
            if(Instance == null)
            {
                Instance = new DialogSingleton();
            }
            return Instance;
        }

        public Dialog getDialog(){
            return this.mDialog;
        }

        public void setDialog(Dialog value){
            mDialog = value;
        }
    }
```

but when I try to access the object this access, but doesn't access the view Button, how is the code when I try access the Singleton:

```
   public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            Time time = new Time();
            time.hour = hourOfDay;
            time.minute = minute;



            /*Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("newTask");
             View viewv = fragment.getView();*/



            Log.d("TaskManager", "A classe é" + DialogSingleton.getInstance().getDialog());

            Button button = (Button) DialogSingleton.getInstance().getDialog().findViewById(R.id.choice_data);
            if(button != null) button.setText("ss");



        }
    }
```

Always the button returns null, please someone now, what is wrong, thanks much.

**UPDATE**

**new_task_dialog.xml**

```
..
<Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pick_date"
        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
        android:id="@+id/choice_data"
        />
    <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/choice_hour"
            android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"
            android:id="@+id/choice_hour"
    />
..
```

Comment: because button won't be the part of layout that is used by Dialog. check which layout you are using for Dialog and is button `R.id.choice_data` part of that layout.

Comment: Yes, is using, i updated my question whit this part of layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Define a Button in the layout file and assign its  ID as 'choice_data'. it should be like

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/choice_data"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/my_button_text"/>
```

`findViewById(R.id.data_choice)` returns *null* when it cannot find the element with ID

Comment: Yes, i have this Button in my new_task_dialog file, add im my question now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the view for the dialog box. Currently your dialog box can not find specified button in the layout. So you need to supply your layout first and then get the hold of the button.

```
public class DialogSingleton {       
   // set the view
   public void setView(int layoutId){
   mDialog.setContentView(layoutId);
   }
}
```

First set your custom layout to the dialog box, and then get the button from that view.

Edit:

Solution 1

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends newTaskFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {...}
```

Solution 2

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
// some code here

Dialog d = DialogSingleton.getInstance().getDialog();
d.setContentView(R.layout.new_task_dialog);
Button b = (Button)d.findViewById(R.id.choice_data);
```

Comment: Try this but return the same java.lang.NullPointerException on Button. I update my question whit my layout file.

Comment: You are using the layout in `newTaskFragment` so intended button is part of `newTaskFragment`. In `TimePickerFragment` you are extending `DialogFragment` which does not have `new_task_dialog.xml`. So either extend `newTaskFragment` or set content view of dialog explicitly in `TimePickerFragment`